# Requiring a user to select a value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a select menu, like so

```
<%= f.select(:size, options_for_select(@sizes_availiable), :prompt => "Select Size") %>
```

With the prompt "Select Size".  The problem is, the user can choose "Select Size" and it still will allow the form to be submitted.  How do I disallow the user from choose that as a value, given that all the sizes are strings as well?

Comment: Here is a solution using a collection_select : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687181/4717639

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's are a couple of things you can do:

```
# as suggested, use :include_blank
f.select :size, options_for_select(@sizes_availiable), include_blank: "Select Size"
# wihch creates an 'option' tag with no value and 'Select Size' text

# or/and add a validation
validates :size, presence: true
validates :size, numericality: true       # or
validates :size, format: { with: /\d+/ }  #
```

However, you should always include validations to prevent malign users from manipulating the form and submitting random stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Use `include_blank` instead of `prompt`.

```
 <%= f.select(:size, options_for_select(@sizes_availiable), {:include_blank => "Select Size"}) %>
```

Than you can validate the `size` in your model.

```
validates :size,   :presence => true
```

Comment: `include_blank` makes absolutely no difference in Rails 4.1.11.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. `include_blank` ALWAYS includes a blank value. `prompt` ONLY includes it if the `select` field has no value yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use :disabled

```
<%= f.select(:size, options_for_select(@sizes_availiable), :prompt => "Select Size", :disabled => 'Select Size') %>
```

Reference:

http://zittlau.ca/ruby-on-rails-disabling-a-select-tag-using-the-select-helper/

Comment: This is my favorite answer.

Comment: Arg! It doesn't work in a collection_select. disabled will match object IDs, but not empty string or prompt string.