# How to disable select_tag prompt in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-select

I've decided that I can't figure out a better way to do dropdowns and for cross-browser support I probably should just stick with a select_tag. I need a prompt, so I created one.

Is there any way you can force the prompt to be disabled so that the user cannot select it? Is there a better way to do this where it doesn't show the prompt in the dropdown list?

Comment: You can also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569819/requiring-a-user-to-select-a-value .

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<%=

prompt = 'select person'

select_tag( 
  name = 'person', 
  options_for_select(
    @names_array.unshift(prompt),  #Add prompt string to front of array
    selected: prompt,
    disabled: prompt,
  )
) 

%>
```

Although, it seems to me that the :prompt option for the select_tag() helper should create an `<option>` that is disabled by default, so you could simply write:

```
select_tag( 
  name = 'person', 
  options_for_select(@names_array),
  prompt: 'select name'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Rails 4.1.  I am unable to disable the prompt using `select_tag`.  It seems not possible based on [the documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag).

I ended up doing this in JavaScript: if the select value is blank, do not submit the form.  (We're using JQuery selectmenu.)

```
$('#select_menu_id').on('selectmenuchange', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    }
})
```