# RoR - Select tag with include_blank disable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select

I want a result like this :

```
<select dir="rtl">
  <option selected disabled>Choose a car</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

With the following code I can only end up with :

```
<%= f.select(:car, xxxxxx, {:include_blank => 'Choose a car', :disabled => 'Choose a car'}) %>
```

=>

```
<select id="xxx" name="xxx">
  <option value="">Choose a car</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

The first option is not disabled...

Comment: Could you try `:disabled => ''`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is as below:

```
<%= f.select(:car, xxxxxx, {:include_blank => 'Choose a car', :disabled => 1}) %>
```

Comment: I think this will disable the entire select tag rather than an option.

Comment: You are correct, I updated my answer. To original asker, you have to specify the select number that is disabled, in this case option 1

Comment: This answer is incorrect. I have provided a solution in the answer below. I have also provided a link to a github repo showing that this answer will not work.

Comment: This does not seem to be working, at least in my Rails 5.2.0.rc project.

Comment: It not working. I think it is a good way to implement something similar in rails core. Especially marerialize.js require that kind of behavior.

Comment: This answer is not working

Answer (score 10):

Ito A's answer will not work in Rails 4.2 (Unsure about earlier versions).
From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)...

> :disabled - can be a single value or an array of values that will be disabled options in the final output.

Therefore, the `:disabled` option should be given a value that matches the value of one of the options in the collection. So, `:disabled => 'volvo'` would disable the option with `value='volvo'`. However, it will not match the include_blank option, because that option is not part of the collection passed into the select method.

Rails select helper does not directly support the desired behavior. However, you can work around it by adding a blank option to the collection as follows.

Create the collection and then add a blank option to it.

```
car_names = %w(volvo saab mercedes audi)
car_names_with_blank = car_names.map{|c| [c, c]}.prepend(['Choose a car', nil])
```

In the view:

```
<%= f.select(:name, car_names_with_blank, {disabled: '', selected: ''}) %>
```

Here's a [link](https://github.com/josephbhunt/rails_disabled_blank_option) to a Github repository with a working example. The example also shows that Ito A's answer and other answers to similar SO questions will not work.

UPDATED: I Have updated my answer with a solution and additional info.

Comment: This is working, and well, on Rails 5.2.0.rc. THANK YOU SO MUCH for posting this, exactly what I was looking for. Mildly surprised that this exact functionality does not exist in Rails. Thank you again.

Comment: @Schwad Glad to hear it finally got fixed! I wish I had taken the time to fix it.  Maybe older versions still need a patch?

Answer (score 4):

I believe they add the functionality in Rails 6.

From the [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/32087):

Enable select tag helper to mark `prompt` option as `selected` and/or `disabled` for `required` field. Example:

```
select :post, 
       :category, 
       ["lifestyle", "programming", "spiritual"], 
       { selected: "", disabled: "", prompt: "Choose one" }, 
       { required: true }
```

Placeholder option would be selected and disabled. The HTML produced:

```
<select required="required" name="post[category]" id="post_category">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">Choose one</option>
  <option value="lifestyle">lifestyle</option>
  <option value="programming">programming</option>
  <option value="spiritual">spiritual</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

An application of the above noted solution follows.

create the application helper function

```
def build_selections(prompt: "Select One", selections: {})
    selections.reverse!.push([prompt, nil]).reverse! 
end
```

then use it in your view:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, build_selections(prompt: 'Select Category',
                           selections: @category.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}),
                           disabled: '' %>
```