# Disable only first option of collection_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

```
<%= f.collection_select :admin_attachment_id, @data['attachments'], :id, :title, { prompt: 'Select banner' }, { class: 'form-control', required: '', 'ng-model': 'banner.admin_attachment_id', 'ng-change': 'get_attachment_thumbnail()', disabled: 'Select banner', selected: '' } %>
```

Renderized:

```
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="required" ng-model="banner.admin_attachment_id" ng-change="get_attachment_thumbnail()" name="admin_banner[admin_attachment_id]" id="admin_banner_admin_attachment_id">
    <option value="">Select banner</option>
    <option value="89">Banner 1</option>
    <option value="94">Banner 2</option>
    <option value="114">Banner 3</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to set the first option as selected item, but must be disabled.  How can I do this?

Comment: I think what you want is to use the `include_blank: "Text"` option. Maybe somethin like this (Answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567614/ror-select-tag-with-include-blank-disable

Comment: It's not working. I've already tried.

Comment: I think you need to put the disabled and selected options in the hash before the one you have them in (with prompt: ).  You appear to have it in the html_options hash, not the options hash.

Comment: I also tried, don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it in a `select_tag`, but you need a form of grouped options:

```
grouped_options = [ 
  [ 'Select banner',
    [
     ['Banner 1', '89'],
     ['Banner 2', '94'],
     ['Banner 3', '114']
    ]
  ]

select_tag('admin_banner[admin_attachment_id]', grouped_options_for_select(:grouped_options))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select

> By default, post.person_id is the selected option. Specify selected: value to use a different selection or selected: nil to leave all options unselected.

So you would put in selected: nil and remove disabled:

```
<%= f.collection_select :admin_attachment_id, @data['attachments'], :id, :title, { prompt: 'Select banner', selected: nil }, { class: 'form-control', required: '', 'ng-model': 'banner.admin_attachment_id', 'ng-change': 'get_attachment_thumbnail()' }
```

I went round and round on this with `collection_select` as this is not mentioned in the docs for that method but only the one for `select`.

Hope this helps!